# AWS Lambda return both a base64 encoded data and a text string in body response

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I am using an AWS Lambda implementation with Node.js to generate a PDF file. I have the following `callback` that returns the pdf in an encoded base64 result. This works great for me:

```
return callback(null, {
    statusCode: 200,
    body: new Buffer(data).toString('base64'),
    isBase64Encoded: true,
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'text',
    },
  })
```

However, I would like to add further information with my response - not just the PDF bae64 encoded data, but some `string` type results that I can use further down my active application connected to this Lambda function. I'd like to return the base64 data and string data, something like this:

```
return callback(null, {
    statusCode: 200,
    body: JSON.stringify(
        {
            message: 'hello world',
            report: new Buffer(data).toString('base64')
        }
    ),
    isBase64Encoded: true,
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'text',
    },
  })
```

But this is failing for me. How would I refactor the above to return both string data and base64 data? I'm also having to force the `isBase64Encoded` setting to `true`, which may clash with my new requirement to return both base64 and normal string data.

Answer (score 1):

The `Content-Type` of your response is not `text` - since you are returning JSON, a `application/json` value would make more sense and might alleviate some of the issues you are having. It would be helpful if the post could be updated with some more relevant details of the errors you are encountering.

One other possible work-around would be to add the `message` (and any other string values) as HTTP headers on the base64 encoded response you already have working. Then your client can decode the HTTP response whose body contains the base64 encoded PDF and HTTP headers `x-custom-message` (or something similar) set to `hello world`.